# What could cause file path NULL only on Galaxy S4 5.0.1?

Tags: android, android-camera

A file is being caught from the camera. We don't use `Intent`, but save a file into `tempfile` object. This is the code

```
private static final int IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1002; //class-wide
private String mCurrentPhotoPath; //class-wide

//...
File photoFile = createImageFile();
Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri);
startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_CAPTURE);

//...
private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
        imageName = mCodeContent + "_" + Integer.toString(randomNumber) + ".png";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(imageName, ".png", storageDir);
        mCurrentPhotoPath = image.getAbsoluteFile().getPath();
        mImageNameList.add(imageName);
        return image;
}
```

But this moment, a variable `mCurrentPhotoPath` is not a null.

However, after a user takes an image, the variable `mCurrentPhotoPath` becomes NULL in the `onActivityResult` so this creates a crash

```
case IMAGE_CAPTURE:
     try {
          Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(new File(mCurrentPhotoPath)); //<---CRASH!!!
          handleCameraImage(uri);
          } catch (Exception e) {
          Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR (IMAGE_CAPTURE)" + "\nmCurrentPhotoPath=" +
                                mCurrentPhotoPath + "\n Log: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
         }
         break;
```

The image path on S4 looks like `/storage/emulated/0/pictures/imageName.png`.

What is causing or deleting `mCurrentPhotoPath`? And only on S4, not on other devices.

PS. I tried saving this value into the shared preferences, but at some point they get deleted as well.

Comment: Your Activity was behind the camera and closed. It is recreated when the camera disappears.  You should use onSaveInstanceState() to save the value. Get it back in onCreate from the savedInstanceState parameter.

Comment: Shared pregerences should always work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For guys in a similar situation. After getting this device I saw the issue.

Namely, S4 built-in camera forces landscape mode. If your app is locked to portrait like ours, then this will create an extra rotation which adds in an extra life cycle change.

`onSaveInstanceState()` will not help you here, but you need to implement `onRestoreInstanceState()` and initialize your objects there as well.

Answer (score 1):

In Samsung phones the orientation will change when camera app is opened. This will cause our activity to restart.

So add configchanges to that activity in manifest file

```
android:configChanges="orientation"
```